# Hover over menu - avoid pushing down content

Tags: html, css

Below are the styles and the html parts of the file. The menu on hover will drop down which in turn is moving the content of the page. How can I change the code so that the drop down menu just appears OVER the content on hover. Z-index isn't helping!

```
<style type="text/css">
      ul{
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        ul li{
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        ul li a{
            visibility: visible;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            color: #003333;
            background: #FF6633;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul li a:hover{
            color: #FF6633;
            background: #FFFF00;
        }
        ul li ul{
            visibility: hidden;
            display: none;
        }
        ul li:hover ul{
            visibility: visible;
            display: block;
        }
        </style>

<body>
<table border="0" align="Center">
<tr><td>
    <ul>
                <li>
            <a href="#">LEBANESE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Falafal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hummus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Baklava</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">ITALIAN</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Pasta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rissoto</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MEXICAN </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Nachos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tacos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quesadilla</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</td></tr></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td>
<div>
Welcome to FoodWiki!
The mission of FoodWiki is to help people map out and explore new food spaces. Through this mission, we hope to enable people to both enjoy food more and live healthier, fuller lives.

The FoodWiki site is a wiki-style data repository to capture and analyze food related information of all kinds. Currently the database contains detailed nutritional information from the USDA nutrient database (sr22), Danish food database, and annotation information from LanguaL.

Using this repository, we've developed vProtein, a computational tool for exploring how plant-based foods can be used as sources of protein. We've published a scientific paper about vProtein and issued a press release that includes some recipes you can try.

Future plans include annotating recipes, food attributes, flavor comparisons, and other food based information. If you have ideas or requests for features, please leave us a comment or email us.

For a guided tour of the features we have online now, please see the overview.

Explore, eat, and enjoy!
</div>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<table id="tab" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td> <image src="css/images/pizza.jpg" height="150" width="150"> </td>
<td> <image src="css/images/nacho.jpg" height="150" width="150"> </td>
<td> <image src="css/images/falafal.jpg" height="150" width="150"> </td>
<td> <image src="css/images/ques.jpg" height="150" width="150"> </td>
<td> <image src="css/images/rissoto.jpg" height="150" width="150"> </td>
</tr></table>
</body>
```

Comment: while using `z-index` always use `position`.

Comment: ...and **don't use tables for layout** !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the parent container's position to relative and then the child elements to absolute in relation to the parent container. Here's a fiddle to show you how to set it up:
http://jsfiddle.net/S7SYA/2/

```
ul{
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
     z-index: 1;
     position:relative;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Might work but, inside tables, positioning doesn't always work as you might expect.

Comment: You answered faster, while I was creating the fiddle.... Same here: http://jsfiddle.net/mrbx3/

Comment: So all i have to do is use tables and div!? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: alright then divs should do! Thank y'all for all the help! :)

Comment: can someone help me with this? Its a similar issue except that now the content is moving horizontally. http://jsfiddle.net/2frZZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only applies to elements that have been given a position `absolute` or `relative`.

Also to safer side add `position:relative` to parent element.

Comment: Its not completely helping!

Answer (score 0):

`position:relative;` on the li and `position:absolute;top:100%;` on the ul

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ju9L3/)